# PHPMailer - Formulario con envío de varios archivos adjuntos

Tags: php, phpmailer

Buenas tardes expertos!

Tengo un formulario en el cual se van a adjuntar 4 documentos (jpg,png, pdf), el funcionamiento ya lo tengo, solamente me falta que al momento de enviar, adjunte los 4 archivos (**actualmente solo adjunta uno**). Estoy usando `PHPMailer` para ello.

inputs:

```
<input type="file" name="uploaded_fdui" id="uploaded_fdui" class="inputfile" accept=".jpg,.png,.pdf" required />
<input type="file" name="uploaded_rdui" id="uploaded_rdui" class="inputfile" accept=".jpg,.png,.pdf" required />
<input type="file" name="uploaded_const" id="uploaded_const" class="inputfile" accept=".jpg,.png,.pdf" required />
<input type="file" name="uploaded_bill" id="uploaded_bill" class="inputfile" accept=".jpg,.png,.pdf" required />
```

Las 4 variables para mis inputs `type"file"` son:

```
$uploaded_fdui = $_FILES['uploaded_fdui'];
$uploaded_rdui  = $_POST['uploaded_rdui'];
$uploaded_const  = $_POST['uploaded_const'];
$uploaded_bill  = $_POST['uploaded_bill'];
```

Y la orden PHPMailer que uso es la siguiente:

```
$mail->AddAttachment($uploaded_fdui['tmp_name'], $uploaded_fdui['name']);
```

Con esto logro adjuntar el primer archivo, pero no me queda claro como hacer para adjuntar el resto, ya que si replico la linea con el resto de variables igual solo envía el primero. He visto algo por alli de hacer un arreglo pero no me quedó claro como es que funciona. Creo que sería la mejor opción ya que de los 4 documentos dos no son necesarios, por lo tanto no van a ser validados como requeridos.

Espero puedan apoyarme, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que aquí lo más importante es saber cómo obtienes los archivos, si en un mismo campo con atributo múltiple o cada uno por separado y nombres diferentes. Por favor, edita la pregunta para agregar esa aclaración y un ejemplo de cómo tratas de agregar otro archivo al correo.

Comment: @Triby son 4 inputs type="file", ya resolví el inconveniente, he publicado como lo hice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me respondo, encontré la respuesta, Si alguien me puede ayudar explicando el funcionamiento del código php del final se lo agradecería, de esta forma la respuesta queda más didáctica.

Agrego a mis inputs `name="attachment[]"` para indicar que voy a formar un arreglo

```
<input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="uploaded_fdui" class="inputfile" accept=".jpg,.png,.pdf" required />
<input type="file" name="attachment[]" id="uploaded_rdui" class="inputfile" accept=".jpg,.png,.pdf" required />...
```

Y para enviar agrego en mi PHP la siguiente condiciónal para crear el arreglo antes de hacer `if($_POST)`

```
// Verificar que se recibieron archivos
if(!empty($_FILES['attachment'])) {
    // No es necesario contar
    // Recorrer el arreglo de nombres por índice
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['attachment']['name']); $i ++) {
        // Comprobar que no hay error en el archivo, incluir índice
        if ($_FILES["attachment"]["error"][$i] == 0) {
            // Obtener ruta del archivo temporal
            $tempFileName = $_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"][$i];
            // Obtener nombre real
            $fileName = $_FILES["attachment"]["name"][$i];
            // Adjuntar al correo
            $mail->AddAttachment($tempFileName, $fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Ahora solo me queda el tema de validar los inputs, ya que al validar con html, al tener los mismos name"", solo me valida el primero.
Saludos.

**Créditos a @Triby por complementar y explicar el código**

Comment: Solo la comparación está mal, porque no estás incluyendo el índice y, además, deberías verificar que no hay error: `if ($_FILES["attachment"]["error"][$i] == 0)`

Comment: @Elboy Lo que hace el código del final es comprobar si existe _attachement_ dentro de `$_FILES`, la variable `$count` contiene el número de elementos en `$_FILES["attachment"]["name"]` y verifica que sea mayor que 0, finalmente añade el _attachement_ al envío del correo usando un bucle para recorrer todos los elementos del arreglo `$_FILES["attachment"]["name"]`

Comment: @Triby encontre el códio, lo implementé pero no lo comprendo del todo, si pudieras tú o alguien más explicar y complementar el código se los agradecería mucho, ya que si estoy aun con el tema de validar si hay error al subir el archivo u otro problema.

Comment: ¿Qué parte del código no entiendes? Lo que colocaste aquí puede resolver el problema, solo cambiando la comparación dentro del `for`, si tus otras dudas no son referentes a adjuntar varios archivos en el correo, lo mejor es publicar otra pregunta. Y, si es acerca de lo mismo, entonces edita la pregunta para colocar tu código actualizado, junto con el formulario y explicando exactamente qué es lo que falla.

Comment: @Triby no es que no lo entienda del todo, creo más o menos descifrar lo que hace, pero no soy bueno para explicar, el código como tal me funciona, pero dices que puede mejorarse, podría solo irme y dejarlo asi ya que me funciona, pero lo ideal es que al ser SO un lugar para aprender, todo quede bien explicadito, asi no pasa como con migo, que alguien más solo copie el código y ya. Si quieres puede editar mi entrada para complementar el código (o comentar lineas), o crear una respuesta y asi poder punturla. Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @Elboy, te tomé la palabra para editar la respuesta y agregar comentarios, aparte de algunas correcciones, como la comparación.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Triby, lo probé y funciona perfecto.